# Finding same files in directory by name and not size

Tags: c#

I want to get diff of two directories based on custom diff comparison. I looked around and found this code that I modified for my requirement, but somehow its returning me incorrect results.

I want to have two FileNamecomparions, one by name and one by size

```
class FileNameCompare : System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<System.IO.FileInfo>
{
    public FileNameCompare() { }

    public bool Equals(System.IO.FileInfo file1, System.IO.FileInfo file2)
    {
        return (file1.Name == file2.Name);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        string fileString = String.Format("{0}{1}", fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length);
        return fileString.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And In my code, I am calling

```
    //Compare files
        FileNameCompare fileNameCompare = new FileNameCompare();


        bool areIdentical = baseList.SequenceEqual(compareList, fileNameCompare);

        IEnumerable<FileInfo> diff = (from file in baseList
                                                      select file).Except(compareList, fileNameCompare);
```

baselist and comparelist of type IEnumerable baseList

Now, when I have two directories with same filename, but different size, areidentical comes as true, but diff still has the one file in baselist.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

On the the same directories, I need to run both name and size comparisons, I need to exactly what files were different on name and what on size, Thats why I seperated out the comparsions.

Edit:

I needed to find the files that were different in size (existing in both the directories), so based on Ramoku's tip, Here is what I have done.

```
        //Get common directories between baselist and comparelist
        IEnumerable<FileInfo> commonList = (from file in baseList
                                            select file).Intersect(compareList, fileNameCompare);

        IEnumerable<FileInfo> diffInListBySize = (from file in commonList
                                                  select file).Except(compareList, fileSizeCompare);
```

Comment: Could it be case sensitivity? In your comparer, try using `return file1.Name.Equals(file2.Name, StringComparsion.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

Comment: I was able to solve the filename comparison problem, but when I try to compare the files by size, I see the files that are only in one directory in the diff list too. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetHashCode` is using the size of the file to determine equality.

Change:

```
public int GetHashCode(System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo)
{
    return fileInfo.Name.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was it.  For some reason, I didnt see this answer on the page anymore. was able to solve the filename comparison problem, but when I try to compare the files by size, I see the files that are only in one directory in the diff list too. How do I avoid the files only in one list to be not in diff list.

Comment: The directories need to be prefiltered to include only the duplicate files first. `Except` only produces the difference from the first list, so files not in the first list won't be included. First you need to join the two directories together by the files they have in common and filter each directory to produce the lists the check for differences.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and added the code to the end of the section. Please let me know if that approach is right. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah the `Intersect` should work fine. You don't really need to use the query syntax unless you're doing some EF or Linq-to-Sql (e.g. `baseList.Intersect(compareList, fileNameCompare)`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean or am I missing something?

```
class FileNameCompare : System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<System.IO.FileInfo>
{
    public FileNameCompare() { }

    public bool Equals(System.IO.FileInfo file1, System.IO.FileInfo file2)
    {
        return file1.Name == file2.Name && file1.Length == file2.Length;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        string fileString = String.Format("{0}{1}", fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length);
        return fileString.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: NO. I want name and size comparisons to run seperately, because I need to find exactly what files were different in name, and what in size.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname.aspx) property, it will give the full path of the file:

```
class FileNameCompare : System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<System.IO.FileInfo>
{
    public FileNameCompare() { }

    public bool Equals(System.IO.FileInfo file1, System.IO.FileInfo file2)
    {
        return file1.FullName == file2.FullName;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        string fileString = String.Format("{0}{1}", fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length);
        return fileString.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you're actually comparing file sizes. Try using `FileInfo.Length` to get the size of the file. See MSDN for additional info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx